# Excel: Rank.AVG With IF/CASE Statement

Tags: excel, sumifs, sumproduct

I have a dataset in Excel that looks like below:

```
A     B    
8    10
9     8
9     8
0     3
0     3
0     3
0     3
```

I want to use the `RANK.AVG` function where it is only taking the rank from values in column B where the value in column A does not equal 0.

For context, this dataset will have a different amount of rows depending on the month and I don't want to modify the formula every time to adjust for only 2 rows in this case.

The current output looks like below:

```
=IFERROR(RANK.AVG(B2,$B$2:$B$8,1),0)

A     B    C
8    10    7
9     8  5.5
9     8  5.5
0     3  2.5
0     3  2.5
0     3  2.5
0     3  2.5
```

The desired output (manual at the moment) would be something like this:

```
=IFERROR(RANK.AVG(B2,$B$2:$B$4,1),0)

A     B    C
8    10    3
9     8  1.5
9     8  1.5  
0     3    0
0     3    0
0     3    0
0     3    0
```

Is there a function to account for this where I can do something like `rank.avg.ifs` similar to `sumifs`? Assuming I can use a `sumproduct` function but not seeing it where it is like rank avg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the ability to add a helper column, then you can use the following formulas:

for `RANK` - `=COUNTIFS(A2:$A$8;">0";B2:$B$8;"<="&B2)`

for `RANK.AVG` - `=AVERAGEIF($B$2:$B$8;B2;$D$2:$D$8)`

[image]

Comment: Hi I got an error when running this: `There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? When the first character is an equal ("=") or minus ("-") sign, Excel thinks it's a formula: you type: =1+1, cell shows: 2. To get around this, type an apostrophe (') first: you type '=1+1, cell shows: =1+1

Comment: Ah I see, needed to replace the semicolon to a comma and that worked!